# Spring Oauth2 - custom exception handler

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security

In Spring Security Oauth2 based authentication when the client sends an access token which needs to be refreshed, the DefaultTokenServices class throws an InvalidTokenException (see at line 235):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.java

the output when this happens is something like:

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: a0cb5ab9-7281-46bd-a9a2-796a04a906c9"
}
```

I'd like to change this output but I got lost. Some other answer suggested setting up a custom **exceptionRenderer** but this didn't work either, my custom exception renderer never gets called in these cases.

Also there's something called an **exception translator** but they werent called either in any case.

Part of my spring config:

```
<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    <property name="exceptionRenderer" ref="myExceptionRenderer" />
</bean>


<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
      <property name="exceptionRenderer" ref="myExceptionRenderer" />
      <property name="exceptionTranslator" ref="listyOauthExceptionTranslator" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" >
 <property name="exceptionRenderer" ref="myExceptionRenderer" />
 <property name="exceptionTranslator" ref="myExceptionTranslator" />
</bean>

<bean id="myExceptionRenderer" class="com.example.exceptions.MyOauth2ExceptionRenderer" />

<bean id="myExceptionTranslator" class="com.example.exceptions.MyOauth2ExceptionTranslator" />
```

The exception renderer:

```
public class MyExceptionRenderer implements OAuth2ExceptionRenderer {

@Override
public void handleHttpEntityResponse(HttpEntity<?> responseEntity, ServletWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Thrown exception");
}
```

}

I also added a custom Exception Mapper which should get ALL the exceptions, but since I assume its another servlet this doesnt really work in this case?

```
@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

@Override 
public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
    System.out.println("MAPPING EXCEPTION");
    return Response.status(200).entity().build();
}
}
```

I could catch cases of **AuthenticationException**, but not any of the **InvalidTokenExceptions**.

Any help regarding this? Where does Spring actually catch this InvalidTokenException and how can I set it up so I can provide a custom output?

Comment: Which version of Oauth2 are you using? `2.0.7` or `1.*`?

Comment: <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
   <spring.security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
   <spring.security.oauth2.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring.security.oauth2.version>
   <spring.cloud.version>1.0.2.RELEASE</spring.cloud.version>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

InvalidTokenException extends `ClientAuthenticationException`. So you can create your own exception by extending `ClientAuthenticationException` and throw this instead of `InvalidTokenException`

```
public class CustomException extends ClientAuthenticationException {

    public CustomException(String msg, Throwable t) {
        super(msg, t);
    }

    public CustomException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
    @Override
    public String getOAuth2ErrorCode() {
        return "my_custom_exception";
    }
}
```

like

```
throw new CustomException("Invalid access token: " + accessTokenValue);
```

In the error that is thrown by InvalidTokenException

```
 {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: a0cb5ab9-7281-46bd-a9a2-796a04a906c9"}
```

`invalid_token` is returned by `getOAuth2ErrorCode()` method of InvalidTokenException and `Invalid access token: a0cb5ab9-7281-46bd-a9a2-796a04a906c9` is the message that you give when you throw the exception.

If you throw

```
 throw new CustomException("This is my custom exception");
```

the error would be shown as

```
{"error":"my_custom_exception","error_description":"This is my custom exception"}
```

`my_custom_exception` is coming from `getOAuth2ErrorCode()` of `CustomException`.

Comment: I can't use a custom exception, since its the Spring Security Servlet and my exception mapper never gets called. I found this also, but I don't know how to configure this via xml?

Comment: @breakline what do you mean by you can't use a custom exception? Throw this custom exception in your `DefaultTokenServices`.

Comment: @breakline the issue you posted talks about changing the `OAuth2EntryPoint`. If you just have to change the exception, you can do it like this.

Comment: If you overwrite DefaultTokenServices.loadAuthentication you either need to throw an AuthenticationException or an InvalidTokenException. If you overwrite the first you get an 500 server error I assume which is the default handler in the servlet. If you overwrite the latter nothing happens since its still a RuntimeException and the Spring Security Servlet deals with it

Comment: that's not necessary, just check this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/uURjt.png I just added this customexception class and it works fine

Comment: But did you overwrite everything? Like, implementing a whole custom Token Services class? And what catches the exception then?

Comment: Why do you want to catch `InvalidTokenException`? It's not supposed to catch. If you want to catch, why are you throwing it here in first place?

Comment: @breakline yes, What  I have shown you  is a cutom token service, but you should be able to do the same thing in default token service also.

Comment: @breakline I am glad that it helped :)

Comment: @Karthik My probelm is just to to add error_code (401) also along with error and error_description. How would I do that?

Comment: @Karthik How can i configure this CustomException class in spring-security xml file??please tell me

Comment: I'm able to change the "error" message in the response body (by creating and throwing a custom exception), but is there any way to change the response code that gets returned? It seems to only want to return a 400, but I'd like to to return 429 (too many requests)

Comment: @user2121620 You should be able to do that in a global exception handler

Answer (score 3):

The answer does not really deliver custom implementation, a custom response will be a point in code where I can access the default response and I can send a POJO instead of it, for example if you want to change `error_description` to `error_info` or anything else, or you may want to add more variables to the response. The solution does exist, but I think it is painful to implement to say the least, as I copy it from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/610):

> This problem has been solved. Follow the workaround below:
>
> 1. Extend `OAuth2Exception` to a new class, such as
>      CustomOAuth2Exception. In the custom class, add some specific
>      properties.
> 2. custom `DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator` and
>      register the custom translator in `AuthorizationServerConfiguration`.
> 3. custom two jackson serializers annotated in `OAuth2Exception` and
>      annotated your `CustomOAuth2Exception` with the two custom
>      serializers.
> 4. use `ObjectMapper` to override initial serializers with
>      custom serializers.

Answer (score 3):

for overriding

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: a0cb5ab9-7281-46bd-a9a2-796a04a906c9"
}
```

you need to inherit ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter 
and override public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config)

sample code

```
package com.org.security;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2Exception;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class CustomWebResponseExceptionTranslator extends DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator {

    /**
     * Modify OAuth2.0 Error Response
     * @param e
     * @return ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception>
     * @throws Exception
     */

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> translate(Exception e) throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity responseEntity = super.translate(e);
        OAuth2Exception auth2Exception = (OAuth2Exception)responseEntity.getBody();
        if (auth2Exception != null) {
            auth2Exception.addAdditionalInformation("data", null);
            auth2Exception.addAdditionalInformation("message", auth2Exception.getMessage());
            auth2Exception.addAdditionalInformation("statusCode", String.valueOf(auth2Exception.getHttpErrorCode()));
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception>(auth2Exception, responseEntity.getHeaders(), responseEntity.getStatusCode());
    }
}





package com.org.security;

import com.org.exception.CustomAuthExceptionEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.WebResponseExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ResourceServerTokenServices;


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenServices;

    @Autowired
    private WebResponseExceptionTranslator oauth2ResponseExceptionTranslator;

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer config) {
        OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler auth2AccessDeniedHandler = new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
        auth2AccessDeniedHandler.setExceptionTranslator(oauth2ResponseExceptionTranslator);
        OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
        authenticationEntryPoint.setExceptionTranslator(oauth2ResponseExceptionTranslator);
        config.tokenServices(tokenServices).accessDeniedHandler(auth2AccessDeniedHandler).authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
    }

}
```

Comment: How to remove existing `error_description` and `error` ?

Answer (score 1):

This my solution to custom AuthorizationServer and ResourceServer exception. May be it will help.

[Spring Security Oauth - Custom format for OAuth2Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55868222/9868643)