# Customize 401 Unauthorized error message in Spring Oauth

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I want to customize 401 Unauthorized error page in spring Oauth 2-2.3.3

Right now I am getting below error form Spring Oauth

```
<UnauthorizedException><error>unauthorized</error><error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description></UnauthorizedException>
```

I have written CustomWebResponseExceptionTranslator class that extends DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator

```
public class CustomWebResponseExceptionTranslator extends DefaultWebResponseExceptionTranslator {
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<OAuth2Exception> translate(Exception e) throws Exception {
       // custom logic
    }
   }
```

I have configured this CustomWebResponseExceptionTranslator in @EnableResourceServer
But this is not getting invoked.
Am I missing anything else?

````
@Import(ServerSecurityConfig.class)
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter  {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint = new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();
        oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint.setExceptionTranslator(new CustomWebResponseExceptionTranslator());
        resources.authenticationEntryPoint(oAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint);
    }

```
````

Comment: please refer here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006285/spring-security-oauth-custom-format-for-oauth2exceptions)

Comment: Thanks it helped.
Actually I saw that post earlier before posting this question, But did not checked thoroughly.

Comment: Can we replace this whole unauthorized json with an HTML page? @priyranjan